# Visualize ObservaleCollection property in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to visualize my *CurrentList.MyItems* in the XAML, which is a property of type *ObservableCollection*. The *CurrentList* is the SelectedValue from a Combobox list and I have already binded to the XAML and initialized in the cs, so that, if you change the element of your list, the element from the Listbox should change too. But I can´t see the values binded to the Listbox and I don´t know why.

**xaml**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllLists}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentList}">
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentList.MyItems}"/>
```

**xaml.cs**

```
public List<ILists> AllLists{ get; } = AllListElements;

private ILists currentList = AllListElements[0];
public ILists CurrentList
{
    get
    {
        return currentList;
    }
    set
    {
        currentList = value;
        ObservableCollection<object> usedIn = new ObservableCollection<object>(currentList.UsedIn);
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

protected ObservableCollection<object> myItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();
public ObservableCollection<object> MyItems
{
    get => myItems;
    set
    {
        new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear how you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` here `OnPropertyChanged` should have a parameter that is the name of the property set. Btw you need to trigger the `OnPropertyChanged` of `UsedIn` as well when you set the `CurrentLUT` property

Comment: You are binding to `CurrentLUT.UsedIn`, what is it? See [mcve].

Comment: @Sinatr _CurrentList.MyItems_: MyItems is a property from the _CurrentList_ (selected value) which gets and sets the in the listbox some items, depending on the selected value of _CurrentList_

Comment: After edit it doesn't become easier to answer. It's pretty confusing what you are actually trying to achieve. Either try carefully explain what is what, so that the reader can follow and see the problem or (better) prepare [mcve]. While preparing you may even discover the problem and find a solution yourself.

Comment: It is however obvious that creating a local variable `ObservableCollection<object> usedIn = ...` has no effect whatsoever.